# U contains a+b+c elements from A u B u C where U intersect A has at least a members, etc. U can be obtained from (A, B, C) choose (a, b, c)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a number of overlapping sets. I need to choose some number of elements out of each one, with no resulting duplicates.

In this case, it is easier to choose the total number of elements from the union of all sets, and check if at least a elements are in A, at least b elements in B, etc.

My intuition wants me to beleive that this is enough to guarantee that a coloring of those elements with a colored A, b colored B, etc. is always possible. I do not need to know what that coloring is, just have a proof on hand that one exists.

Example:

A={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} choose 3
B={2,4,6,7,9,10} choose 2
C={3,4,5,9,11,12} choose 2

U={1,2,3,4,5,6,7} has 7 elements shared with A, 4 shared with B, and 3 shared with C. (7,4,3)>=(3,2,2). And can be colored ${1,2,3} \bigcup {6,7} \bigcup {4,5}$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. I was going to edit your post to fix the formatting (there's a MathJax guide [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), but it's not clear to me exactly what your question even is. Could you edit it to clarify, please?

Comment: The question was answered before it was closed, so no need to reopen. Basically, was the simple test enough to prove U could be constructed? No.

Comment: @Paul Even if you are not looking for more answers, it is still nice to improve the formatting and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that some basic conditions are satisfied:

- $\lvert A\rvert \ge a$, etc.
- $\lvert A\cup B \cup C\rvert \ge a + b + c$

Then this is always possible by construction:

1. Pick any $a$ elements from $A$ to form $U_1 \subset A$; $\lvert U_1\rvert = a$;
2. Pick any $b$ elements from $B$ to form $U_2 \subset B$;
3. Pick any $c$ elements from $C$ to form $U_3 \subset C$.
4. The union $U_1 \cup U_2 \cup U_3$ may contain fewer than $a+b+c$ elements; choose enough from the remaining unpicked ones $(A\cup B \cup C)\setminus (U_1\cup U_2\cup U_3)$ to form $U$.

---

A colouring does NOT always exist. A counter example is

- $A = \{ 1\}$; $a = 1$
- $B = \{ 1\}$; $b = 1$
- $C = \{ 2, 3 \}$; $c = 1$

Then the only possible choice for $U = \{ 1, 2, 3\}$ (because $\lvert A \cup B \cup C\rvert = a+b+c = 3$). Yet the $1 \in U$ needs to be coloured both $A$ and $B$, which is impossible.